# I cannot center the Button component in Material-UI using Styled Components

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I am quite new to Material UI @ next, and I like the fact that it supports Styled Components.

However, I am struggling in aligning the **Button** component to the center through Styled Components. I only manage to align it by using the *styles* technique such as this:

```
const styles = {
  container: {
    textAlign: "center"
  }
};

class Landing extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    ...
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <Button variant="raised" color="primary">
        I am a button
      </Button>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is something that I like to avoid, and instead use the Styled Components such as:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  text-align: "center";
`;
```

However, for some reason it is not working although they look exactly identical. Can someone explain whether text-align and textAlign are pointing to the same CSS property?

Comment: Duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63937897/4225103

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works using styled component here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from "react-bootstrap/es/Button";
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Container = styled.div`
 text-align: center;
`;

class Landing extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <Container>
            <div>
                <Button color="primary">
                    I am a button
                </Button>
            </div>
          </Container>
    )};
};
```

You have to wrap the styled component which you have taken. Here I've taken **container** and then inside the container, I've added the needed CSS.

For more information and usage about the styled component, you can visit this URL - https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics

Thanks