# How to center a button in Material-UI

Tags: css, reactjs, button, material-ui, alignment

I couldn't figure out how to center buttons in Material-UI. This is the code I have:

```
function BigCard(props) {
    const { classes } = props;
    return (
    <div>
        <Card className={classes.card}>
        <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="display1" className={classes.title}>
            Start Funding!
            </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions >
            <Button size="small" color="primary" className={classes.actions}>
            Share
            </Button>
            <Button size="small" color="primary">
            Learn More
            </Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
```

How can I center my button?

Comment: Add code as text instead of images. Also, try to add a minimal verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 53):

You can use `Box` element

```
<Box textAlign='center'>
  <Button variant='contained'>
     My button
  </Button>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 32):

you could use the [override with classes](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes) in the material ui doc,

**FIRST WAY**

You can do something like :

```
//Add your justify css in your styles const
const styles = {
    ...
    root: {
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
};
```

And use the classes props to add this to your CardActions component :

```
 <CardActions classes={{root: classes.root}}>
```

**SECOND WAY (easier)**

OR You can use the style directly on your component, but i advise you to train how to use classes if you're working alot with material-ui

Just do something like :

```
<CardActions style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
```

Answer (score 18):

For use cases that avoid defining css

```
<Grid container justify="center">
  {props.children}
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 7):

Quick and dirty:

```
<Button style={{margin: '0 auto', display: "flex"}}>
  NEXT
</Button>
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I did it with Material - UI

```
import {Typography, Button} from '@material-ui/core';

 <Typography align='center'>
    <Button
      color='primary'
      size='large'
      type='submit'
      variant='contained'
     >
      Sign Up
    </Button>
  </Typography>
```

Answer (score 7):

From **MUI v5**, you can apply the custom styles using the [`sx`](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content) props. Because `CardActions` layout is already flex, you only need to set its `justify-content` to `center`.

Using `sx` instead of inline styles like the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51021339/9449426) help reduce the CSS specificity, and make it easier to override the CSS in the future

```
<CardActions sx={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
  <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
</CardActions>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 51010599/how-to-center-a-button-in-material-ui]

Answer (score 4):

What I tried is below and is also shown in official videos of material ui on youtube.

```
<Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={4} lg={4}
    style={{
        textAlign:'center' // this does the magic
    }}
>
    <Button>
         NEXT
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Thanks and best wishes

Comment: Tried all of the above and none of it worked but this!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use two properties: display and justify-content

```
<CardActions display='flex' justifyContent='center'>
```

Comment: I was working it with Grid material ui. Added <Grid display="flex" justifyContent="center"> and only with both those properties defined it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**This will centre your button horizontally**

```
 <Button
                size="medium"
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    justifyContent:"center",
                    backgroundColor: purple[500],
                    '&:hover': {
                        backgroundColor: purple[700],
                     },
                }}
                
            >
            Get Hired
       </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a Box wrapping around the button

```
 <Box
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: { xs: 'column', md: 'row' },
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}
    >
        <Button>Click me</Button>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may sound counter-intuitive but what worked for my case (slightly different than yours) was to use the `fullWidth` attribute in the Button element.

Here is my scenario (MUI v5):

```
<Grid container alignItems={'center'} >
  <Grid item>
    <Button fullWidth variant='contained' >Click Me!</Button>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap element in this center

```
.center{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, putting textAlign directly into the button sx-props worked:

```
 <Button 
    sx={{ textAlign: 'center',}}
    > 
    Click
 </Button>
```